# Interval Notation of the Increasing and Decreasing Sections of a Quadratic

Tags: quadratics

This is the quadratic y=-4x^2+4x+3.

Here is the graph. [image]

I know that the increase and the decrease of a graph has to do with the y value.

From this, I know that from negative infinity to 0.5, the function is increasing. From 0.5 to positive infinity the graph is decreasing.

In interval notation
Increase: (-infinity, 0.5)
Decrease: (0.5, infinity)
I was wondering if the bracket on the 0.5 is a square bracket or parentheses.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Increasing" or "decreasing" refer typically to having a positive or negative derivative respectively. In that light, it should be clear that $y'(0.5) = 0$ - i.e. neither positive nor negative, so at $x = 0.5$, $y$ is neither increasing or decreasing.

Therefore, the appropriate notation would be with the parentheses, i.e. $(-\infty,0.5)$ and $(0.5,\infty)$, since you don't want to include $x = 0.5$.

Comment: To clarify (just in case you haven't encountered calculus), the derivative of a function is just its slope. The slope at $x=0.5$ is $0$, that is, the function is flat at that x-value, therefore, it is neither increasing nor decreasing. It is the point of change **between** increasing and decreasing.